# On Win8, is there a program/script that can back up a 4 tb drive to two 2 tb ones?

Tags: backup

Without using any RAID setups is there a program or script that could take the contents of one 4 tb drive and copy them to two 2 tb drives? I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Lots of backup programs will allow you to create backups that "span" across disks.  Common practice, e.g. if you want to back up a hard drive to optical media, it'd have to be broken up . . .

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8 introduces a technology called "storage spaces" which allows a user to combine multiple disks to create a storage space "pool" so you could use 2 x 2TB disks to create a 4TB space.

You can use different types of disks - connected internally or externally - to create a storage space. Example: a 2TB external USB3.0 disk + an internal 2TB SATA disk could create a virtual 4TB disk that the system will see as a single 4TB usable space.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/storage-spaces-pools

Comment: Of course storage spaces are not supported by any other operating except Windows 8+ and the stability is yet to be proven

Comment: Agreed @Ramhound - OP: please bear that in mind. Also: I have just re-read the OP and I believe I may have overlooked a potential problem... Storage spacess will work, but they operate very much like RAID0 - disk capacities simply added together. If one fails you potentially lose the lot. You can create mirrored storage spaces which allow some points of failure - you'll need more disks, however. As others may suggest: it may be worth looking into a RAID setup. They are tried and tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Just to clarify what I'm trying to do - I have a workstation with 25 TB of media data across 11 disks. I then have those files mirrored on 11 drives that I connect to the workstation when I need to make backups. This is a low-budget project, so I'm not able to use many RAID arrays - I am using consumer drives, and it is cheaper just to connect the back-up drives to the computer when I need to than to have them in their own RAID arrays when I need to backup.

I'm about to replace two 2 TB drives with one 4 TB drive, but use the two 2 TB drives as backup for the 4 TB.

Comment: So to avoid any complications with software RAID, or any expenses with external hardware RAID, I want to be able to attach the two 2 TB drives with a HD dock when need be, but have a script or program automatically split the 4 TB drive's data onto two smaller drives. Right now I just manually find out which files to put on each drive.